# Movie with guy demoing Iron-Man-style jetpack

Tags: story-identification, movie

About 8 years ago, I saw a clip from a movie while I was waiting in a check-out line. In it, a guy was flying a red jetpack for (presumably) the first time. The background to the scene was a couple of gray buildings.

It wasn't a suit, it was a jetpack, and he activated it by doing something with his arms and little joysticks popped up into his hands. He had to maneuver these to fly it.

What movie is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [*Jingle all the Way*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116705/)

This was one of the standout entries of Arnold Schwarzeneger's family comedy phase. It was released in 1996, and generally gets a lot of play during the Christmas season, so it's conceivable that it could have been playing in a supermarket 8 years ago.

The plot of the movie revolves around [Ahnold](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ahnold) trying to find a particularly popular action figure (based on a kind of Iron Man/[Rocketeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketeer) character) as a Christmas present for his son (pre-*Star Wars* Jake Lloyd, fact fans). At the end of the movie, a chain of wacky hijinks leads to him being in a parade dressed up as the character. The suit has a functioning jetpack, controlled by joysticks popping out of wrists, which he activates in an attempt to save his son from a bad guy.

If you ignore some of the funky editing (added by the uploader), the scene in question is on YouTube:

Although it is a full suit, rather than just a jetpack, it hits too many of your points for me to ignore.

Comment: This is what I thought as well. Hard to think the OP would forget that Schwarzenegger was in it though. He's one of the few actors that is hard to miss or forget.

Comment: That's it! I remember the joysticks popping out just like that. Thx!

Comment: I want to downvote everyone involved here for reminding me that this movie exists.

Comment: @phantom42 So, you go suggest _[The Rocketeer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJL9aVp_1jE)_ as the answer then.

Comment: "a chain of "wacky" "hijinks" leads to..." FTFY